# Jest - mock function runs but .toHaveBeenCalledTimes() stays 0

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, testing, jestjs

I'm trying to test if the function `searchRestaurantsHelper` is called when `searchRestaurant` is called.

The problem is the received number of times is always 0.

Here's the test:

```
import axios from 'axios';

import Yelp from './Yelp';

import {
  getRestaurantInfoHelper,
  searchRestaurantsHelper,
  searchDefaultRestaurantsHelper,
} from './utils';

jest.mock('./utils.js');
jest.mock('axios');

describe('Testing searchRestaurantsInfo', () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks();
  });

  test('searchRestaurantsInfo called once and returns something', async () => {
    await Yelp.searchRestaurantsInfo('q_IoMdeM57U70GwqjXxGJw');

    getRestaurantInfoHelper.mockImplementation(() => 'foo');

    expect(getRestaurantInfoHelper).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    await expect(
      Yelp.searchRestaurantsInfo('q_IoMdeM57U70GwqjXxGJw')
    ).resolves.toEqual('foo');
  });

  test('axios.get called twice', async () => {
    await Yelp.searchRestaurantsInfo('q_IoMdeM57U70GwqjXxGJw');

    expect(axios.get).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2);
  });

  
});

describe('Testing searchRestaurants', () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks();
  });

  test('searchRestaurantsHelper called once', async () => {
    axios.get.mockImplementationOnce(() => {
      const response = { data: { businneses: ['foo'] } };
      return Promise.resolve(response);
    });

    searchRestaurantsHelper.mockImplementation(() => 'foo');

    await Yelp.searchRestaurants({
      what: 'tacos',
      where: 'rome',
      sortBy: 'rating',
    });

    expect(searchRestaurantsHelper).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });

  test('axios.get called once', async () => {
    await Yelp.searchRestaurants({
      what: 'tacos',
      where: 'rome',
      sortBy: 'rating',
    });

    expect(axios.get).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });

 
});
```

I create an axios mock since `searchRestaurants` wouldn't run `searchRestaurantsHelper` if `response.data.businesses.length === 0`.
Then I create a mock function for `searchRestaurantsHelper` but apparently it's not being called.

Here's searchRestaurants()

```
const Yelp = {
  // Returns restaurant search resuts

  async searchRestaurants(text) {
    try {
      let response = await axios.get(
        `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://api.yelp.com/v3/businesses/search?limit=12&term=${text.what}&location=${text.where}&sort_by=${text.sortBy}`,
        {
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${YELP_API_KEY}`,
            'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
          },
        }
      );

      if (response.data.businesses.length === 0) {
        return [];
      }

      return searchRestaurantsHelper(response);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  },
}
```

And searchRestaurantsHelper() in './utils'

```
export const searchRestaurantsHelper = (response) =>
  response.data.businesses.map((business) => {
    return {
      id: business.id,
      image: business.image_url,
      name: business.name,
      url: business.url,
      price: business.price,
      phone: business.phone,
      categories: business.categories[0].title,
      address: business.location.display_address[0],
    };
  });
```

Can anyone explain to me what I'm doing wrong? I've been stuck for a while...
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem. Don't truncate imports or other module-related parts because they are relevant. It's unknown in which module searchRestaurantsHelper is located and how it was mocked. The problem you describe suggests that mocked function wasn't used, otherwise the assertion would pass.

Comment: *since searchRestaurants wouldn't run searchRestaurantsHelper if response.data.businesses.length === 0* - you can't be sure about that because you didn't assert the result that `Yelp.searchRestaurants` returns, which is a bad practice for tests. For starters, it's `businneses` in one place and `businesses` in another.

Comment: @EstusFlask I've included imports and module-related parts. The problem as you suggested was the typo  ```businneses```/``` businesses```.  Once fixed that the test passes.

Answer (score 0):

For `jest` to track the function calls you have to `spyOn` this function, like so:

```
const searchRestaurantsHelper = jest.spyOn(
    searchRestaurantsHelper, 'searchRestaurantsHelper');
```

The names are misleading since you imported a function from a component with the same name. To avoid it, you could rename your component i.e. to start with uppercase and also rename your spy i.e. to `searchRestaurantsHelperSpy`.